# android-how to remove lines on map

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm drawing lines between two position on map and it works fine .

I need to remove them when I want to draw new line .
This is my code :

```
PolylineOptions lineOptions;
ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
                    for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                        HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j); 
                        if(j==0){   
                            distance = (String)point.get("distance");                       
                            continue;
                        }else if(j==1){
                            duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                            continue;
                        }
                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 
                        points.add(position);                       
                    }
                }
lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(3);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

I tried map.clear() , didn't work . 
How can I clear all lines on the map ?

thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Polyline> polylineArraylist;
```

In onCreate Method

```
polylineArraylist = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
```

Update your code with this one

```
// flusing all Markers drawn previously
for (int icount = 0; icount < polylineArraylist.size(); icount++) {
Polyline polyline = polylineArraylist.get(icount);
polyline.remove();
}

Polyline mPolyline = null;
PolylineOptions lineOptions;
ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
                    for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                        HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j); 
                        if(j==0){   
                            distance = (String)point.get("distance");                       
                            continue;
                        }else if(j==1){
                            duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                            continue;
                        }
                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 
                        points.add(position);                       
                    }
                }
lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(3);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
mPolyline = googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

Add Polyline to ArrayList

```
polylineArraylist.add(mPolyline);
```

Comment: thanks very much for the reply , I did what you said but didn't work . I logged the polylineArraylist.size() and it has only 1 item . Is that correct?

Comment: you're right , it clears the lines but when I choose next two city , all those last lines + new lines draw on map again .